# Active Directory remove user from GroupA if member of GroupB

Tags: active-directory, user-management, groups

In Active Directory, how do I efficiently remove all users from GroupA who are members of GroupB? Basically I want to subtract B from A.

Have now:

```
AAA         BBB
---         ---
Alice       Alice
Charlene    Bruce
Chuck       Chuck
```

Desired:

```
AAA         BBB
---         ---
            Alice
Charlene    Bruce
            Chuck
```

I have the user lists in csv at the moment but can reorganize quickly to something else if needed:

```
logon, group
alice, AAA
alice, BBB
bruce, BBB
...
```

I'm not an AD admin, just a user who has write privileges for these groups.

Comment: Down voters please explain why, so that I might learn from my mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: This is considered a "write a script for me" question, a category of questions considered problematic by many of the people here.

Comment: I think people should communicate via comments first, not via downvotes as downvotes do not communicate anything, other than that this annoyed me, perhaps. But that's just me, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell Active Directory Web Services. Comes with all Domain Controllers 2008 R2 or better by default.

```
# This foreach loop enumerates through all members of the AAA group.
Foreach ($Usr In Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'CN=AAA,CN=Users,DC=Contoso,DC=com')
{
    # If the 'MemberOf' array of $Usr's group memberships contains 'BBB', then...
    If ((Get-ADUser $Usr.SamAccountName -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf -Contains 'CN=BBB,CN=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com')
    {
        # Remove that user from 'AAA'.
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity 'AAA' -Members $Usr.SamAccountName
    }
}
```

That will remove all members of group 'AAA' who are also members of group 'BBB'. No CSV needed.

If you are using less than Powershell 3, use `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` before you start using AD cmdlets.

Comment: took me a devil of a time to get the right CN= syntax for our weird AD setup, but this example was enough to get me through to the end of my first powershell script that does real work. Thanks!

Comment: @mattwilki: You can always use this powershell query to get the correct `DistinguishedName` without having to do the search manually: Get-ADGroup [ad-group-name]